# If $f(z)=z^me^{g(z)}P(z)$ is of order $\rho$ then $P(z)$ has order less than $\rho$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function of order $\rho$. Using Weierstrass factorization theorem we can write $f(z)=z^me^{g(z)}P(z)$ where $g$ is an entire function and $P$ is the canoncial product of the zeros of $f$. I read in a book that the oder of $P$ is smaller or equal then $\rho$. Can someone explain me why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|z^{n}P(z)| <e^{ |z|^\epsilon}$ for $|z|$ sufficiently large. This gives $|f(z)z^{n}P(z)| <e^{|z|^{\rho}+|z|^{\epsilon}}<e^{|z|^{\rho+\epsilon}}$ for $|z|$ sufficiently large. This is true for each $\epsilon >0$ so we are done.